# I am not getting the site when I make the request through HTTP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the site www.mytest.com (in php)

I'm getting the site, when i request it as https://mytest.com,

But when I request the site as: http://mytest.com, it's not working.

Can anyone tell me what is the reason?

There is this .htaccess file on the server:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://mytest.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Is the web server set up to accept connections on port 80, and is there a VirtualHost directive set up for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the last line really say:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mytest.com/$1 [R,L]`

If it does, add a pound sign (#) in front to comment it out.  For example, change it to:

`# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mytest.com/$1 [R,L]`